# If certain category, use different CSS class

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am completely new to custom wordpress development.  I have an article page that has three possible post categories.

I need an If, Else If, Else statement that will allow me to change the color scheme of the title block for the category.  Ex. If category 1, use class 'blue' else if cat2, use class 'red', else class 'yellow'.

The issue I'm running into is I have php inside those if else statements for the category and image url.

Please advise.  Thanks

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 ">
    <!--Check category for color scheme -->
<?php if ( in_category( 'Data Governance' )) { ?>
    <div class="categoryHeading blue">
        <?php query_posts('category_name=Data Governance'); 
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 hidden-xs">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/category_icon.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <h1 class="toUpper"><?php the_category(', '); ?></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>                                  
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php
$cat_colors = array();
$cat_colors['cat1'] = 'blue';
$cat_colors['cat2'] = 'red';
$cat_colors['cat3'] = 'yellow';
$categories = get_the_category();
?>
```

...skipping a lot of stuff...

```
 <div class="categoryHeading <?php echo $cat_colors[$categories[0]->slug;?>">
```

This assumes that you have assigned each post a single category...or that you at least are only interested in the first one. 
cat1, cat2, cat3 in the array refer to category slugs.

HTH,

=C=

Comment: This broke my page...Thanks though

Comment: <div class="categoryHeading <?php echo $cat_colors[$categories[0]->slug];?>">

Comment: Sory, left off  the trailing ]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much other code changes based on the category.  If it is only the div color, you can do something like this:

```
    <?php
    if ($category=="category 1")
        $divColor="blue";
    elseif ($category=="category 2")
        $divColor="red";
    else
        $divColor="yellow";

    echo "<div class=\"$divColor\">";
    ?>
```

Otherwise you may need to either set more variables, or possibly include the entire section three times, using the same if, elseif, else statements.